# Can I install Ubuntu Unity Dash in other desktop environments?

Tags: unity-dash, elementary

I really like Elementary OS, which is based on Ubuntu. The only thing I didn't like is the launcher/dash, which isn't fast enough and doesn't search all the files, whereas I find Ubuntu dash very good. I know I can use alternatives like Synapse, but I just like the elegant design of the Ubuntu Dash. So can I install it somehow on elementary OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the founder of elementary OS, Daniel Foré:

"[It's not possible to use the Unity Dash without the entirety of Unity](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2q7tm8/ubuntu_dash_home_in_pantheon/)"